# .Net Static Class Property Scope as it Pertains to the Runtime

Tags: .net, static, runtime

Let's say that I have two .Net applications running on a single machine. Both applications access a static property in a class. Considering the following scenario in sequential order:

---

**Application A**

```
FooClass.MyStaticString = "A";
```

**Application B**

```
FooClass.MyStaticString = "B";
```

---

**Application A**

```
Console.WriteLine(FooClass.MyStaticString);
```

---

Would the result be "A" or "B"? I'm just curious *how* static .Net statics really are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are limited to the specific [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx). Each application at a minimum has its own unique AppDomain, so the static property/field is *not* shared across the applications.  It would be "A" as a result. Similarly, if you fired up multiple AppDomains within one process, the static property/field would not be shared between those either.